# How to run bash commands from Node.js and get result

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I want to run a bash script on my server using a Node js function and get the result back in Node  through a callback. Sample script is as follows -

> grep -c "eventName" 111data.csv

Is this possible? I looked at the following module but looks very complex. Does anyone know of a way this can be done?

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/bashjs

Comment: Check out https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Why not use `exec` and `child_process`? https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a command

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const grep = exec('grep -c "eventName" 111data.csv', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
    console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
  }
  console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
  console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
});

grep.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
});
```

Just modified the example from [the Node.js article](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/child-processes/how-to-spawn-a-child-process/). Didn't actually test it